# Laravel eloquent find in array of objects column

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

I have a table called `services` with multiple columns and one column named `staff_assigned` with this content:

```
[{"user_id":"15549","price":"100"},{"user_id":"15548","price":"300"},{"user_id":"15552","price":"95"},{"user_id":"15553","price":"600"}]
```

How can I find all services where user_id is 15548 with Laravel eloquent? 
Note that

```
Service::where('staff_assign->user_id', "15548")->get();
```

doesn't work because column contains array of objects.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
->whereJsonContains('staff_assign',  ['user_id' => '15548'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Service::where('user_id', '=' , "15552")->get();
```

Just add the '=';

Comment: user_id is not column. staff_assign is column with array of objects.